# Linux, programmatically(C) generating a list pf partitions on a disk drive

Tags: linux, partition

I need a way to get a list of partitions associated with a particular device in C, preferably by calling a set of library routines,  as opposed to calling exec, popen etc and parsing.

I've seen a few wrong examples, on the net, all with the same error,
They start with the device, get the number of partitions then generate a list of numbers 1-num_partitions and append that to the device. Ok. That's confusing so let me give an example.

If the program is told the device is /dev/sdq. Preliminary use of libblkid tells you that /dev/sdq has five partitions on it. So the approach generates a list of partitions. /dev/sdq1,..., /dev/sdq5.

The problem, of course, is that there is no guarantee that the partitions are labeled by the first n numbers. In the example, the partitions could be /dev/sdq1, /dev/sdq5,/dev/sdq6,/dev/sdq9,/dev/sdq10. The algorithm therefore would tell you that partitions labeled 2-4 exist when they don't and miss entirely the partitions named 6,9,10.

Comment: libdevmapper is what you want

Comment: @Voigt since I am concerned with "physical" partitions I think not.

Comment: Are you positive device-mapper doesn't show both logical and physical volumes?